# What does apliction.run mean in visual studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hello the project I was working on saved incorrectly or something idk but I wasn't able to access the form design so I had to make it new in a different project and just copy over the code but when I did there was an error for the code

`Application.run(new BeatUpADummySim());`

The error says: `"The type or namespace name 'BeatUpADummySim' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"`

What would I need to change to fix it?

Comment: According to your problem, I suggest that you can check if your current winform project has BeatUpADummySim form. If exists, please provide all the code in the program.cs. If not, please change the form to the correct name.

Answer (score 1):

`Application.Run` launches a form as the principal for your desktop application and keeps it running until the form is closed.

If you have copied that line from other application you must change the type to your main form type.